# How do you make a 3D city population graphic?

Tags: graphics3d, histograms

I want to make a graphic that has the shape of a country, finds all the cities of that country, gets their coordinates and populations and turns that into a SmoothHistogram3D with the population being the z value.

I tried this, but apparently that's not how it works:

```
SmoothHistogram3D[
 DeleteCases[
  CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ CityData[{All, "Mexico"}], 
  Missing["NotAvailable"]], 
 DeleteCases[CityData[#, "Population"] & /@ CityData[{All, "Mexico"}],
   Missing["NotAvailable"]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this is probably what you're after:

```
dat = DeleteCases[({CityData[#, "Population"], 
    CityData[#, "Coordinates"]} & /@ 
    CityData[{All, "Mexico"}]), {___, _Missing, ___}];
func = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[
    WeightedData[dat[[All, 2]], dat[[All, 1]]]], {x, y}];
ra = func[[2, 0, 1]];
Plot3D[Log10@func, {x, ra[[1, 1]], ra[[1, 2]]}, {y, ra[[2, 1]], 
    ra[[2, 2]]}, PlotRange -> {-5, All}]
```

[image]

Note that you were deleting the `Missing` cases for the Population and Coordinates separately, but these two lists of data do *not* correspond to the same lists of cities, you can see this by checking that their lengths are different. The expression above only includes cities that have both datum.

I took the log of the function to get better depth contrast, otherwise the image is dominated by huge spikes from the very largest cities.

Comment: How would you go about drawing the shape of the country on the "ground" of the graphic?

Comment: @Guillochon: have you tested that code with version 10? It looks like you need to replace Quantities for it to work in version 10, e.g. add a line `dat =dat /. q_Quantity :> QuantityMagnitude[q]` ...